# MVC 5 EF 6 Project using LINQ to SQL Fails on Production IIS-7 Server

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I suspect it's a web.config or IIS issue, but either way, I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a MVC 5 EF 6 project that works perfectly in VS, on the development server and production server.  I need to use LINQ to SQL in one instance, instead of LINQ to Entity.  When I build/run the project in VS, LINQ to SQL works perfectly.  As soon as I publish the project to the development server and test it, I get "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.usp_SearchDemographics'.  I've tried modifying the web.config, but I don't know enough about it yet to resolve this myself.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Here's the LINQ to SQL:

```
var st = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "nvchrSearchTerm",
    Value = searchTerm
};

var sf = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "nvchrSearchField",
    Value = searchField
};

var _searchResults = db.Database.SqlQuery<DemographicsSearchModel>("EXEC dbo.usp_SearchDemographics @nvchrSearchTerm,@nvchrSearchField", st, sf).ToList<DemographicsSearchModel>();
```

Here's the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />


  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --><sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup><!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="SecureLDAPConnectString" connectionString="LDAP://myldap.xxx:636/DC=mydomain,DC=xxx" />
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=mydbserver\mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PNetContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=PNetContext-20141016085722; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|PNetContext-20141016085722.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=DBContext-20150312154547; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DBContext-20150312154547.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PIMSModel" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=PIMSModel-20150318081342; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|PIMSModel-20150318081342.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <add name="P_PUBSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PubEntityModel.csdl|res://*/PubEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/PubEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=mydbserver\mydb;initial catalog=P_PUBS;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="PINTRANETEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PNetModel.csdl|res://*/Models.PNetModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.PNetModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=mydbserver\mydb;initial catalog=PINTRANET;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="PIMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PIMSModel.csdl|res://*/PIMSModel.ssdl|res://*/PIMSModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=mydbserver\mydb;initial catalog=PIMS;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings> 
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="CDC\IIS_IUSRS" />
      <allow roles="CDC\IUSR" />
      <allow roles="CDC\Domain Users" />
      <allow roles="CDC\PDEV" />
      <allow roles="CDC\PNET" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <membership defaultProvider="MyADSecureMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyADSecureMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="SecureLDAPConnectString" connectionUsername="testdomain\administrator" connectionPassword="password" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <!--<customErrors mode="Off" />-->
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Home/Error.cshtml" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Views/Home/Error.cshtml" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Views/Home/Error.cshtml" />
    </customErrors>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>

    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls></pages>
  <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules></system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <!--<authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication>
          <providers>
            -->
      <!--<add value="Negotiate"/>-->
      <!--
            <remove value="NTLM"/>
          </providers>
        </windowsAuthentication>
      </authentication>-->
    </security>


  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxMin" publicKeyToken="21ef50ce11b5d80f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.14.5506.26196" newVersion="5.14.5506.26196" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.1.0" newVersion="5.6.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.9.0" newVersion="1.4.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<elmah>
    <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data/Elmah" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
    <!--<security allowRemoteAccess="false" />-->
    <errorMail from="aipcomputerbranch@cdc.gov" to="aipcomputerbranch@cdc.gov" subject="ELMAH Error" async="true" smtpServer="outlook@cdc.gov" />
</elmah><location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.
      -->
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="CDC\IIS_IUSRS" />
        <allow roles="CDC\IUSR" />
        <allow roles="CDC\Domain Users" />
        <allow roles="CDC\PDEV" />
        <allow roles="CDC\PNET" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location></configuration>
```

Comment: As long as you're here, be advised that Entity Framework Model First and Database First (anything using EDMX) is deprecated. Despite the name, Code First can be used with existing databases, and is both the preferred option now and the only option from EF7 forward. See: http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I recently that about edmx.  We will plan on updating this in the next version of our project.

Answer (score 0):

Egg on face!  The EF model dll was still pointing to production data.  And, the production database server didn't yet have the stored procedure in question.  The app worked as it should.